# can hashmap have duplicate keys in multithreading environment

Tags: java, hash, collections, hashmap

If we do not use `Collections.synchronizedMap()` and let say i have a **multi-threaded environment**.

I know about *race condition, re-sizing* issue etc.

My question is can there be a case 2 threads `Ta` and `Tb` having same object and trying to put into a map.

Can there ever be 2 entries, if not how it is prevented. Is there a fraction of time diff between 2 put calls of 2 different threads running at same time.

As per my understanding, for both `Ta` and `Tb` both will check before putting, so can there be case of duplicate keys here.

Taking into consideration that we have overridden `hashcode` and `equals` properly.

Comment: I think they will always override each other. If you do not properly synchronize it you probably get a concurrentexception.

Comment: why are you asking? surely you don't intend to use a non-threadsafe container in such a scenario?

Comment: Because _both will check before putting_, there you have your race condition: the insert is not an atomic (a single undivisable) operation, but it consists of atleast 2 operations which may interfere when `Ta` is not properly synchronized with `Tb`.

Comment: No, there can never be duplicate keys in a `HashMap` because of how it's implemented. There would only be a race condition.

Comment: @PatrickParker I was asked this question, i know i can use synchronized features, but that is like a workaround, i was more interested in actually knowing what exactly happens, like for read i can say, that `read might happen` before `put call`, so it might return null, but my concern was for simultaneous write for same object

Comment: the question is fundamentally unsound. you said the we are using an unsychronized map, which may be any type of map. You did not specify HashMap. Even if we know it is a HashMap, you must specify a particular version and implementation of Java, since the implementation is allowed to change as long as it fulfills the specification. so I would ask the person who asked you, why they are asking.

Comment: This sounds like a typical job interview question, where there's no right or wrong, but they want to see how you improvise in the given situation. So here's another thought in form of an analogy to Schrödinger's cat: because the two threads can both insert their value for the same key at the same time and we don't know which thread actually inserts it's value, we must assume both values to be correct. We cannot know the result before looking what's inside the map. Which implicitly means there are 2 entries for the same key. Hope, that's not to far fetched :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc for `HashMap` states:

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads
>   access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the map structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally. (A
>   structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more mappings; merely changing the value associated with a key that an
>   instance already contains is not a structural modification.) This is
>   typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally
>   encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map should be
>   "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap method.

So the docs say that you *must* synchronize access somehow, but do not say what will happen if you do not. That means that the behaviour when you do this is *undefined* -- all bets are off.

You can look at [the source code for `HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap) yourself. The heart of `put` is:

```
     for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
         Object k;
         if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
             V oldValue = e.value;
             e.value = value;
             e.recordAccess(this);
             return oldValue;
         }
     }

     modCount++;
     addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
     return null;
```

(Edit - this is the implementation in Java 6. Java 8's is dramatically different -- which reinforces the point)

We can speculate about the outcome if two threads attempt this simultaneously -- but it is pretty difficult to reason about. Sometimes it will result in two entries with the same key, sometimes it won't. It depends on timing.

`TreeMap`'s `put()` is completely different of course, and its quirks when abused in this way will be different.

Any such behaviour is a quirk of the implementation, and the implementation may change in future without warning, because we are talking about undefined behaviour. The implementation makes no promises to you that it won't:

- silently drop entries
- go into an infinite loop
- `NullPointerException`
- claim huge amounts of memory
- corrupt the store so that entries with other keys are lost
- make previously removed entries reappear
- create entries containing garbage from heap memory
- etc.

The docs *do* state that a modification from elsewhere, while an `Iterator` is working on the object, will cause the `Iterator` to throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` -- but this is a different concern from synchronization, and could still happen if you used a `SynchronizedMap`

In summary, don't do it.